# Where are ReportLab Demos described in User Guide to be found?

Tags: reportlab

In the ReportLab User Guide it says:

> The colortest.py script in reportlab/demos/colors demonstrates the
> different ways in which reportlab can set up and use colors. Try
> running the script and viewing the output document, colortest.pdf.
>
> This shows different color spaces and a large selection of the colors
> which are named in the reportlab.lib.colors module.

When I installed the ReportLab site-package it created a folder called reportlab but the only sub-folders installed were fonts, graphics, lib, pdfbase, pdfgen and platypus but no demos.

Is the documentation in error or am I misunderstanding where to look for them?

Either way I'm keen to find a wider list of ReportLab's named colors rather than trying to guess which may be valid.

Comment: Some of the ReportLab material referenced in the documentation is not part of the open source distribution but is instead only available with the paid ReportLab product.  Unfortunately I think the demos are part of that.  Thankfully, though, if you dig through the source code, you'll find the place where the named colors are defined, although if I recall correctly there is only a limit set of named colors in the open source version of ReportLab.  You're probably better off specifying colors by code rather than name.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - acting on your advice I found colors.py in C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib and found a list of all the "color constants -- mostly from HTML standard".

Comment: Reportlab demos can be found at https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/src/f082a5b30170dafeef0c5688038cc63c19959fde/demos/?at=default

Comment: Thank you @PolyGeo. Feel free to update your own answer with it. I'll be glad that is of use to somebody. It can start like: "The demos are not distributed with the installable library but you can find them in the source code repository..." I think the content of the link explains it self very well. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commented by AlessMascherpa:

> The demos are not distributed with the installable library but you can
>   find them in the source code repository at [Bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/src/f082a5b30170dafeef0c5688038cc63c19959fde/demos/?at=default).

Alternatively, here are the named colors (color constants) available in ReportLab 2.5 which I found in C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\colors.py:

```
# color constants -- mostly from HTML standard
aliceblue =     HexColor(0xF0F8FF)
antiquewhite =  HexColor(0xFAEBD7)
aqua =  HexColor(0x00FFFF)
aquamarine =    HexColor(0x7FFFD4)
azure =     HexColor(0xF0FFFF)
beige =     HexColor(0xF5F5DC)
bisque =    HexColor(0xFFE4C4)
black =     HexColor(0x000000)
blanchedalmond =    HexColor(0xFFEBCD)
blue =  HexColor(0x0000FF)
blueviolet =    HexColor(0x8A2BE2)
brown =     HexColor(0xA52A2A)
burlywood =     HexColor(0xDEB887)
cadetblue =     HexColor(0x5F9EA0)
chartreuse =    HexColor(0x7FFF00)
chocolate =     HexColor(0xD2691E)
coral =     HexColor(0xFF7F50)
cornflowerblue = cornflower =   HexColor(0x6495ED)
cornsilk =  HexColor(0xFFF8DC)
crimson =   HexColor(0xDC143C)
cyan =  HexColor(0x00FFFF)
darkblue =  HexColor(0x00008B)
darkcyan =  HexColor(0x008B8B)
darkgoldenrod =     HexColor(0xB8860B)
darkgray =  HexColor(0xA9A9A9)
darkgrey =  darkgray
darkgreen =     HexColor(0x006400)
darkkhaki =     HexColor(0xBDB76B)
darkmagenta =   HexColor(0x8B008B)
darkolivegreen =    HexColor(0x556B2F)
darkorange =    HexColor(0xFF8C00)
darkorchid =    HexColor(0x9932CC)
darkred =   HexColor(0x8B0000)
darksalmon =    HexColor(0xE9967A)
darkseagreen =  HexColor(0x8FBC8B)
darkslateblue =     HexColor(0x483D8B)
darkslategray =     HexColor(0x2F4F4F)
darkslategrey = darkslategray
darkturquoise =     HexColor(0x00CED1)
darkviolet =    HexColor(0x9400D3)
deeppink =  HexColor(0xFF1493)
deepskyblue =   HexColor(0x00BFFF)
dimgray =   HexColor(0x696969)
dimgrey = dimgray
dodgerblue =    HexColor(0x1E90FF)
firebrick =     HexColor(0xB22222)
floralwhite =   HexColor(0xFFFAF0)
forestgreen =   HexColor(0x228B22)
fuchsia =   HexColor(0xFF00FF)
gainsboro =     HexColor(0xDCDCDC)
ghostwhite =    HexColor(0xF8F8FF)
gold =  HexColor(0xFFD700)
goldenrod =     HexColor(0xDAA520)
gray =  HexColor(0x808080)
grey = gray
green =     HexColor(0x008000)
greenyellow =   HexColor(0xADFF2F)
honeydew =  HexColor(0xF0FFF0)
hotpink =   HexColor(0xFF69B4)
indianred =     HexColor(0xCD5C5C)
indigo =    HexColor(0x4B0082)
ivory =     HexColor(0xFFFFF0)
khaki =     HexColor(0xF0E68C)
lavender =  HexColor(0xE6E6FA)
lavenderblush =     HexColor(0xFFF0F5)
lawngreen =     HexColor(0x7CFC00)
lemonchiffon =  HexColor(0xFFFACD)
lightblue =     HexColor(0xADD8E6)
lightcoral =    HexColor(0xF08080)
lightcyan =     HexColor(0xE0FFFF)
lightgoldenrodyellow =  HexColor(0xFAFAD2)
lightgreen =    HexColor(0x90EE90)
lightgrey =     HexColor(0xD3D3D3)
lightpink =     HexColor(0xFFB6C1)
lightsalmon =   HexColor(0xFFA07A)
lightseagreen =     HexColor(0x20B2AA)
lightskyblue =  HexColor(0x87CEFA)
lightslategray =    HexColor(0x778899)
lightslategrey = lightslategray
lightsteelblue =    HexColor(0xB0C4DE)
lightyellow =   HexColor(0xFFFFE0)
lime =  HexColor(0x00FF00)
limegreen =     HexColor(0x32CD32)
linen =     HexColor(0xFAF0E6)
magenta =   HexColor(0xFF00FF)
maroon =    HexColor(0x800000)
mediumaquamarine =  HexColor(0x66CDAA)
mediumblue =    HexColor(0x0000CD)
mediumorchid =  HexColor(0xBA55D3)
mediumpurple =  HexColor(0x9370DB)
mediumseagreen =    HexColor(0x3CB371)
mediumslateblue =   HexColor(0x7B68EE)
mediumspringgreen =     HexColor(0x00FA9A)
mediumturquoise =   HexColor(0x48D1CC)
mediumvioletred =   HexColor(0xC71585)
midnightblue =  HexColor(0x191970)
mintcream =     HexColor(0xF5FFFA)
mistyrose =     HexColor(0xFFE4E1)
moccasin =  HexColor(0xFFE4B5)
navajowhite =   HexColor(0xFFDEAD)
navy =  HexColor(0x000080)
oldlace =   HexColor(0xFDF5E6)
olive =     HexColor(0x808000)
olivedrab =     HexColor(0x6B8E23)
orange =    HexColor(0xFFA500)
orangered =     HexColor(0xFF4500)
orchid =    HexColor(0xDA70D6)
palegoldenrod =     HexColor(0xEEE8AA)
palegreen =     HexColor(0x98FB98)
paleturquoise =     HexColor(0xAFEEEE)
palevioletred =     HexColor(0xDB7093)
papayawhip =    HexColor(0xFFEFD5)
peachpuff =     HexColor(0xFFDAB9)
peru =  HexColor(0xCD853F)
pink =  HexColor(0xFFC0CB)
plum =  HexColor(0xDDA0DD)
powderblue =    HexColor(0xB0E0E6)
purple =    HexColor(0x800080)
red =   HexColor(0xFF0000)
rosybrown =     HexColor(0xBC8F8F)
royalblue =     HexColor(0x4169E1)
saddlebrown =   HexColor(0x8B4513)
salmon =    HexColor(0xFA8072)
sandybrown =    HexColor(0xF4A460)
seagreen =  HexColor(0x2E8B57)
seashell =  HexColor(0xFFF5EE)
sienna =    HexColor(0xA0522D)
silver =    HexColor(0xC0C0C0)
skyblue =   HexColor(0x87CEEB)
slateblue =     HexColor(0x6A5ACD)
slategray =     HexColor(0x708090)
slategrey = slategray
snow =  HexColor(0xFFFAFA)
springgreen =   HexColor(0x00FF7F)
steelblue =     HexColor(0x4682B4)
tan =   HexColor(0xD2B48C)
teal =  HexColor(0x008080)
thistle =   HexColor(0xD8BFD8)
tomato =    HexColor(0xFF6347)
turquoise =     HexColor(0x40E0D0)
violet =    HexColor(0xEE82EE)
wheat =     HexColor(0xF5DEB3)
white =     HexColor(0xFFFFFF)
whitesmoke =    HexColor(0xF5F5F5)
yellow =    HexColor(0xFFFF00)
yellowgreen =   HexColor(0x9ACD32)
fidblue=HexColor(0x3366cc)
fidred=HexColor(0xcc0033)
fidlightblue=HexColor("#d6e0f5")
```

Comment: Sweet :) Cheers @PolyGeo

Answer (score 1):

A PDF file displaying all the colours and their names is generated by the test suite.

The tests are in reportlab-2.7.zip\reportlab-2.7\tests

Un-zip (if you need to) and run:

python runAll.py

One of the many documents this creates is test_lib_colors.pdf